# Call juste once the function of scrollSpy Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use scroll spy from bootstrap and I would like to call just once the function which activate the navigation with a button.

I explain, I don't want to use entirely the scroll spy, just when I click on a button for example. And the rest of the time I don't want to use it.

I don't know which function is called by the event "onscroll" from Bootstrap.

**EDIT:** This is a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/xfsAWsLADkW6F98exC4P?p=preview

```
$(function() {
            function spy() {
              $('#myScrollspy').addClass('scrollspy');
                $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.scrollspy' });
                $('#myScrollspy').removeClass('scrollspy');
            }
            button_spy.onclick = spy;
});
```

In this, I activate scroll spy and disable with the button but it worked just once. So, I asked myself which is the function called by the bootstrap scroll spy to call it juste once but I didn't find it.

Comment: It is good..if you show code using jsfiddle or post your code also...

Comment: You need like this way right **http://themes.lucky-roo.com/berg-v1.2/HTML_Template/index.html**

Comment: I don't want that something is happening when I see the waypoint, I just want to put the class "active" in my `<li>` when I click on the button, but the rest of the time i don't want to use the scroll spy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show active section
Add this css

```
       ul.nav-tabs {
    width: 140px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.067);
}
ul.nav-tabs li {
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
ul.nav-tabs li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
ul.nav-tabs li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
ul.nav-tabs li.active a, ul.nav-tabs li.active a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0088cc;
    border: 1px solid #0088cc;
}
ul.nav-tabs li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul.nav-tabs li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
ul.nav-tabs.affix {
    top: 30px; /* Set the top position of pinned element */
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/jvg3ce1t/1/)**

Comment: Thanks :) But I want to scroll in my page and if I click on the button the menu changed. But if I scroll again the menu doesn't change.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lkb5jmgL/
this is the fiddle with the button which highlight the menu but stay i don't know how disable this.

Comment: go through this tutorial **http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-scrollspy.php**

Comment: I already read this but it doesn't talk about the disable of this or the function which is called by the scroll spy to activate the `<li>`. :/

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I want ^^ You use the scroll spy and i don't want to use it just the function which is called by it to add the class `active` to the menu or if it's not possible I want to disable it, activate it to put `active` to the menu and disable/remove it just after. but thanks for helping me ^^